# TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() take no keyword arguments

Tags: python

Been trying to get data to print to an outfile and keep getting this error. When I print the data to the screen (printrec()), everything works, but writerec() does not. I'm not very familiar with python and I've tried several different versions of output.write().

```
def printrec():
    x = 1
    while x < len(reccomendlist):
        print("User-ID",x,': ', "Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][0],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][1],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][2],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][3],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][4], sep = '')
        x += 1

def writerec():
    with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    #encoding = 'utf-8'

        x = 1
    while x < len(reccomendlist):
        output.write("User-ID",x,': ', "Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][0],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][1],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][2],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][3],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][4], sep = '')
        x += 1

    output.close()
    #with open("./output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        #x = 1
   # while x < len(reccomendlist):
        #text_file.write("User-ID",x,': ', "Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][0],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][1],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][2],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][3],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][4], sep = '')
        #x += 1
```

Comment: I don't know how to attach my code like other people do and the UI for posting a question is not user friendly for people new to stack overflow @enzo

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/9997212

Comment: The short answer is that `print` and `write` work differently. You can't add a bunch of things to write like you do with print. Build a single string and write that.

Comment: Should be fixed now, thanks for that, I could only get it to post random lines in the block before and not the whole thing which is why I originally had a photo @td

Comment: lets not downvote just because the poster took a few minutes to tidy up the post.

Comment: @tdelaney I need to write it to the file in that specific format. Is there a way for me to keep the format I have (e.x. what I have as the print statement in printrec() ) but put it into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need the line `output.close()`, the with-block already closes the file for you.
2. Your indentation is wrong. It should be

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    x = 1
    while x < len(reccomendlist):
        output.write("User-ID",x,': ', "Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][0],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][1],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][2],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][3],', ',"Movie-ID",reccomendlist[x][4], sep = '')
        x += 1
```

3. You can iterate over `reccomendlist` by doing

```
for x, element in enumerate(reccomendlist):
    element
```

instead of

```
x = 1
while x < len(reccomendlist):
    element = reccomendlist[x]
    x += 1
```

4. You can't add the `sep` parameter to `write`, this is a `print` parameter. Use print with the `file` parameter:

```
for x, element in enumerate(reccomendlist):
    print("User-ID",x,': ', "Movie-ID",element[0],', ',"Movie-ID",element[1],', ',"Movie-ID",element[2],', ',"Movie-ID",element[3],', ',"Movie-ID",element[4], sep = '', file=output)
```

Depending of your Python version, it can be even more readable:

```
for x, row in enumerate(reccomendlist):
    print(f"User-ID{x}", end=': ', file=output)
    print(', '.join(f"Movie-ID{element}" for element in row), file=output)
```

Answer (score 0):

In very short:
Instead of using **output.write(myClass)** use **print(myClass, file=output)**